# plotly.express choropleth only showing some information from geojson

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, choropleth

I am trying to create a choropleth map using `plotly.express` When the figure loads it only shows one color (bottom of the color scale) and shows the outline of a singular region. This clearly means it is reading the geojson but not displaying properly.

My `df` looks as such:

```
     NUTS level nuts318cd  ...  2016.0    2017
 5        NUTS3     UKC11  ...  4457.0  4569.0
 6        NUTS3     UKC12  ...  4092.0  4137.0
 7        NUTS3     UKC13  ...  1692.0  1697.0
 8        NUTS3     UKC14  ...  7913.0  8088.0
 10       NUTS3     UKC21  ...  5872.0  6015.0
 ..         ...       ...  ...     ...     ...
 230      NUTS3     UKN12  ...  2256.0  2310.0
 231      NUTS3     UKN13  ...  2263.0  2287.0
 232      NUTS3     UKN14  ...  2555.0  2578.0
```

and my code is:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.choropleth(data_frame=df, geojson=spatial, locations='nuts318cd',
                       featureidkey='properties.nuts318cd', color='2017',
                       scope='europe'
                   )
fig.update_geos(showcountries=False, showcoastlines=True,
                showland=False, fitbounds="locations")
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

All data for this project is freely avaliable to reproduce if needed.

If anyone understand, help would be appreciated.

Graph output:

[image]

Comment: Please, provide full code and data.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you're hitting an issue with the "winding" of the polygons in your GeoJSON: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2354#issuecomment-638742767