# Plotly.express choropleth only shows one color

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, choropleth

I am trying to create a choropleth using `plotly.express`. The figure is able to load, but it only shows one color. I can mouse over each feature and it displays the relevant information, but not in variable color. This implies that it is reading the geojson but not displaying properly. [u/geds133 had the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61966708/plotly-express-choropleth-only-showing-some-information-from-geojson), but I am unable to contact them or comment due to low reputation.

Here is my "predictions" df:

```
import pandas as pd
predictions = pd.read_csv("Predictions_DF_2002.csv")

predictions.head()
```

```
huc12           Predicted PRBT   Std
170102120304    30.677075        23.348831
170102120603    31.362211        23.784001
90400010201     5.697461         7.688427
100301040401    3.493039         5.36472
170101011208    4.421055         11.924093
```

I am attempting to match the DataFrame with a property within the geojson file:

```
#Read in geojson
import geopandas as gpd
import json


hucs = gpd.read_file(~/"HUC.geojson")

#Populate hucs['properties'] (i.e. convert to plotly-readible geojson-type)
hucs = json.loads(hucs.to_json())

#Print Properties for sanity check
print(hucs['features'][0]['properties'])
```

```
#...<a bunch of stuff we don't care about> 
{'huc12':170102120304}
#...
```

Thus, I can use the `featureidkey` parameter to specify where to match the values of `locations` as written in [the docs](https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/#choropleth-maps-with-gochoropleth). Here is the code I use to create the choropleth:

```
fig = px.choropleth(predictions,
                    geojson=hucs, color='Predicted PRBT',
                    locations='huc12', featureidkey='properties.huc12',
                    color_continuous_scale="Viridis", labels={'Predicted PRBT':'Predicted % RBT'})
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations",visible=False)
fig.show()
```

And here is what the output shows. Note that mouse-over shows relevant information:
[image: Choropleth Output]

My geojson and csv are available for download [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yUBsWTeOUbKe8kkNQlE_tUKBsO_fV5h0/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The geojson must be unwound before plotting:

```
#Read in geojson
import geopandas as gpd
import json


hucs = gpd.read_file(~/"HUC.geojson")

#Populate hucs['properties'] (i.e. convert to plotly-readible geojson-type)
hucs = json.loads(hucs.to_json())
```

```
from geojson_rewind import rewind
hucs_rewound = rewind(hucs,rfc7946=False)


fig = px.choropleth(predictions,
                    geojson=hucs_rewound, color='Predicted PRBT',
                    locations='huc12', featureidkey='properties.huc12',
                    color_continuous_scale="Viridis", labels={'Predicted PRBT':'Predicted % RBT'})
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations",visible=False)
fig.show()
```

See https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2354#issuecomment-638742767
and https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2619
[image: Solved]